# how to insert a CSV file into TDengine?

Tags: csv, insert, tdengine

The data is a CSV file with comma as separator and timestamp and string field value quoted by single quotes，how can i insert it into TDengine?

I am now using SQL to achieve that Single row or multiple rows specified with VALUES can be inserted into a specific table. just like this:

INSERT INTO d1001 VALUES (NOW, 10.2, 219, 0.32);

Answer (score 0):

try "INSERT INTO table_name FILE csv_name"